# Cannot get value of button using xpath and selenium despite many variations tried

Tags: python, selenium, button

Was able to get the value of the buttons on this page with xpath, then went to similar page on the same website, now the code comes up empty when trying to grab all the button values.

I have tried all of these xpath variants to try and get the value attribute of the submit buttons on the page.

Here is the html

```
<td><input type="submit" class="submitLink" name="alinkvalue" value="19 CR 003595" onclick="setSearch(3);submitForm()"></td>
```

These are the xpath variants I have tried and have failed to grab the value.  They don't error, just provide no value when run.

```
 # case_links = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('submitLink')  #does not get the buttons
 # case_links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@type='submit']")  #does not get the buttons
#case_links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@name='alinkvalue']")
#case_links = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('submitLink')
#case_links = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#search > table:nth-child(2) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(5) > td:nth-child(1) > input:nth-child(1)')
```

I am expecting to retrieve '19 CR 003595' as the 'value' of the button.

Comment: did you try .get_Attribute('value' ) on these links?

Comment: Do you mean `case_links` ends up as an empty list?

Comment: The xpath seems correct. Does it return case_links list with size greater than 0? If yes, please try to loop through the list and perform .get_Attribute('value') in order to get the values for each element.

Comment: Sorry about the omission there.  The case_links list returns empty on each of the attempts above.